# How to hide suite bar ribbon and header

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

I want to remove / hide "sharepoint suite bar ribbon and header" ? It is the yellow part in my hardcopy.

Is there a way to do it ?

Best Regards,

Pierre

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Modern UI does not offer an editable master page, nor it supports script link custom action. Although it is not recommended to customize the page via changing the relying on the dom as its structure may get changed overtimes, you can use SPFx extension to inject CSS/JS to hide the related dom elements.

- https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/blob/master/samples/react-application-injectcss/README.md
- https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-step-procedure-to-add-a-js-file-to-all-pages-in-a-spfx-modern-pages-using-sharepoint-framework-extension/

BR